# Jsonpath filter out arrays

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have the following json string

```
{
   "721": {
      "sdfsdfsdf": {
         "hjkhjk": {
            "image": [
               "data:image/svg+xml;base64,",
               "PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9"
            ]
         },
        "sfgw4": {
            "image": "image"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

and i use this json path exp

```
$.*.*.*.image
```

which finds

```
[
  [
    "data:image/svg+xml;base64,",
    "PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9"
  ],
  "image"
]
```

But i want to ignore arrays in my result. Expected result:

```
[
  "image"
]
```

Any ideas how to achieve it? There is no way to tell if the image field is array or string from the other fields.

Comment: If you know how the value of the image property looks like (e.g. always `image` or `.*jpg`) you could use a match operator like this `$..[?(@.image=~ /image/i)].image`

Comment: Are you using [Jayway jsonpath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) implementation of Java? If yes you can try the `noneof` filter operator
`$..[?(@.image.* noneof $..image.*)])`